# How to stop Pandas from changing lists of texts into strings when saving dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have several lists of words that I want to store in excel and reload them later. However, when I save the dataframe to excel, it stores the lists of words as strings. Therefore, when I reload the dataframe, I only get every character including the [] and ' ". My question is how to use pandas to save lists of words into excel and later reload them as lists to work on. If pandas to excel is not an efficient way, could you show me how to do this using json or pickle?
Below is the code I used:

```
# Create the dataframe
textlist = [["Ain't",'no','sunshine'],['when',"she's",'gone']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['textlist'])
df.textlist = pd.Series(textlist).values

# Test the current dataframe
text = df.textlist.tolist()
for i in text:
    print('i: ', i)
    for j in i:
        print('j: ', j)

# Write data to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path + '1.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()

# Reload the data and test the reloaded dataframe
df1 = pd.read_excel(path + '1.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
text1 = df1.textlist.tolist()
for i in text1:
    print('i1: ', i)
    for j in i:
        print('j1: ', j)
```

Here is the result of the first block before saving to excel, which is correct:

```
i:  ["Ain't", 'no', 'sunshine']
j:  Ain't
j:  no
j:  sunshine
i:  ['when', "she's", 'gone']
j:  when
j:  she's
j:  gone
```

Here is the result of the second block after saving and reloading from excel:

```
i1:  ["Ain't", 'no', 'sunshine']
j1:  [
j1:  "
j1:  A
j1:  i
j1:  n
j1:  '
j1:  t
j1:  "
j1:  ,
j1:   
j1:  '
j1:  n
j1:  o
j1:  '
j1:  ,
j1:   
j1:  '
j1:  s
j1:  u
j1:  n
j1:  s
j1:  h
j1:  i
j1:  n
j1:  e
j1:  '
j1:  ]
i1:  ['when', "she's", 'gone']
j1:  [
j1:  '
j1:  w
j1:  h
j1:  e
j1:  n
j1:  '
j1:  ,
j1:   
j1:  "
j1:  s
j1:  h
j1:  e
j1:  '
j1:  s
j1:  "
j1:  ,
j1:   
j1:  '
j1:  g
j1:  o
j1:  n
j1:  e
j1:  '
j1:  ]
```

Comment: This is really confusing and sure we can help but.... The most confusing part is: Have you considered not to use excel to store data like this and instead use the json-string format or csv or maybe pickle (python variables)?

Comment: Also, storing lists in pandas is rarely the best approach regardless of the excel aspect

Comment: @AntonvBR: I have tried csv but it somehow converted some of texts to non-acsii format, so when I reloaded it into dataframe it created non-ascii errors (not in this example though). I have never tried json-string or pickle so I am not sure about the format and I/O operation.